# How to change indexing while using \begin{enumerate}?

Tags: indexing

I am writing theoretical solutions for an exercise with multiple parts. However, not all questions are theoretical and so let's say that out 5 questions, I only need the indices 1, 3 and 5. I can suppress the indices by using * as shown below:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1)
\item 3)
\item 5)
\end{enumerate}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better workaround to these situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is the solution to your problem:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1)]
\item[3)]
\item[5)]
\end{enumerate}
```

Which putputs this:

[image]

Comment: Great! This works for me. Thanks!